# Do vendors ever get new legendary items?

Tags: fallout-4

Do vendors like the ones in diamond city ever get new legendary items if you already bought the ones they had?

Comment: I've certainly never seen them get any new ones. It might be possible that they get them at a certain level. I haven't gotten up to 50 yet.

Comment: @DCShannon yeah neither have I. I have one level 4 vendor in Sanctuary, and he hasn't had any new legendary items since the first one. And just for fun, I went through and bought all the legendary items from all the vendors I could think of. I was hoping they'd spawn new ones, kind of like the some vendors do with power armor parts. FWIW I'm at level 109.

Comment: Do the vendors ever have non-unique legendary items? If not, then the finite number of unique items would imply that the answer is no.

Comment: That's a great point, I'm not sure, I wasn't paying much attention to what the items were (btw, I bought it all with purified water. I have a lot of extra water generated to buy stuff with).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

There are only a set number of Unique Legendary Items that are vendor specific. Most of the time a vendor will only have 1 legendary weapon and sometimes multiple pieces of armor.

Once you buy them, they will never restock another unique legendary weapon or piece of armor.